# Select an element to display an error message in jQuery

Tags: jquery

I've this HTML:

```js
    $('a[data-action="get-resume"]').click(function(event) {
        var client_conditions = $('[name="client_conditions"]');
        if(client_conditions.prop('checked') == false) {
            client_conditions.next('.error-message').removeClass('hide');
            return false;
        }
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row">
        <div class="col-xl-12 mb-4">
            <div>
                <input id="client_conditions" class="checkbox-style" name="client_conditions" type="checkbox">
                <label for="client_conditions" class="checkbox-style-1-label">Lorem ipsum.</label>
            </div>
            <div class="error-message text-danger hide">Required</div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <a href="#" data-action="get-resume">Validate</a>
```

On click on `Validate`, it checks if `client_conditions` is checked or not.

It's working well but the error message isn't display.

```
client_conditions.next('.error-message').removeClass('hide');
```

Do you know why ?

Thanks.

Comment: I am not sure if .next leaves the current DOMs depth. So perhaps it will only find elements inside the parents div?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `closest()` and `find()` method of jquery to get closest `.row` and then get the `error-message` div .

***Demo Code*** :

```js
$('a[data-action="get-resume"]').click(function(event) {
  var client_conditions = $('[name="client_conditions"]');
  if (client_conditions.prop('checked') == false) {
    //get closest .row and then find error message div
    client_conditions.closest(".row").find('.error-message').removeClass('hide');
    return false;
  } else {
    client_conditions.closest(".row").find('.error-message').addClass('hide');
  }
});
```

```css
.hide {
  display: none
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-xl-12 mb-4">
    <div>
      <input id="client_conditions" class="checkbox-style" name="client_conditions" type="checkbox">
      <label for="client_conditions" class="checkbox-style-1-label">Lorem ipsum.</label>
    </div>
    <div class="error-message text-danger hide">Required</div>
  </div>
</div>
<a href="#" data-action="get-resume">Validate</a>
```